# -replace, how to only match the first dot?

Tags: powershell

```
$Var = "Dog.Jumping.png", "Horse.Jumping.gif", "Cat.Jumping.jpg", "Lion.Jumping.tiff", "Shark.Jumping.svg", "Cow.Jumping.psd"
$Var -replace '\.', ' - '
```

The above seems to find both "." characters, I am only interested in first one. Something like `$Var -replace '\.?', ' - '` does not make sense, I am genuinely stumped here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The strings you have in your array seem to be file names. Proper file system objects consist of the properties `Basename` and `Extension`. I'd recommend using the `Basename` property instead of the `Name` property you seem to use at the moment what includes the `Basename` AND the `Extension`. ;-)  ... how do you populate the array?

Comment: @Olaf. Bad example on my part then, this is more about the `-replace` operator and regex. I cant seem to find a way to turn of global. As in return after finding the first match.  Its not being populated by another operation, its the first thing that came to mind when i was typing an example with two reoccuring characters in all elements. Thanks!

Comment: gaberiel_: as far as I know, _Global_ flag can't be turned off in .NET regex engine. The way around it is using the `Count` argument of the regex instance as in my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To offer a conceptually simpler alternative to the helpful existing answers (which are regex-focused):

- The [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator allows you to limit the number of tokens resulting from the split, via its optional 2nd operand.
- The [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join) operator allows you to join the resulting tokens with a separator of choice.

Applied to a single string:

```
# -> 'Dog - Jumping.png'
'Dog.Jumping.png' -split '\.', 2  -join ' - '
```

<sup>As an aside: `split`'s - rarely used - optional *3rd* operand supports *additional* splitting options, such as `'SimpleMatch'`. Using it would cause the 1st operand to be interpreted as a *literal* string rather than a regex, obviating the need to escape [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) metacharacters such as `.` with `\`:

`'Dog.Jumping.png' -split '.', 2, 'SimpleMatch'  -join ' - '`</sup>

Applied to an array of inputs:

```
@(
  "Dog.Jumping.png"
  "Horse.Jumping.gif"
  "Cat.Jumping.jpg"
  "Lion.Jumping.tiff"
  "Shark.Jumping.svg"
  "Cow.Jumping.psd"
) | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $_ -split '\.', 2  -join ' - '
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

The following might do what you're looking for:

```
$Var -replace '^(.+?)\.', '$1 - '
```

Another similar option would be:

```
$Var -replace '^([^\.]+)\.', '$1 - '
```

See https://regex101.com/r/1dhUz2/2 for details.

Using an instance of [`Regex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-7.0) offers an even simpler way since one of the [`.Replace` overloads have a `count` argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-string-system-int32)):

```
$Var | ForEach-Object { $re = [regex] '\.' } {
    $re.Replace($_, ' - ', 1)
}
```

However, as [Olaf noted in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf), since these seem to be valid file names and assuming you have gathered them with `Get-ChildItem`, you could use literal replacement on the `.BaseName` ETS property which already excludes the extension.

Answer (score 6):

Complementing [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75645211/7571258), another way is to use a *[positive lookbehind assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)*. Such an assertion adds a requirement to the following RegEx pattern. It must be preceded by the pattern defined in the assertion.

```bash
$var -replace '(?<=^[^\.]+)\.', ' - '
```

**Output:**

```
Dog - Jumping.png
Horse - Jumping.gif
Cat - Jumping.jpg
Lion - Jumping.tiff
Shark - Jumping.svg
Cow - Jumping.psd
```

Let's decipher the sub expression `(?<=^[^\.]+)`:

- `(?<=` starts a positive lookbehind assertion
- `^` anchors the following pattern to the beginning of the string
- `[^\.]+` any character that is not a dot, one or more times (`+`)
- `)` ends the assertion

The advantage of an assertion is that the assertion itself won't take part in the match, so only the dot will actually be replaced.

[RegEx101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/aZDgny/1)

Comment: I did not know about this positive assertion thingy, look to be very usefull. Thanks for this great answer!